# How do I get the 401 status code and redirect to a page in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am building a Meteor app (v 1.2.2) and using Iron:Router (v 1.0.7) as my routing engine. My customer requires me to use their custom authentication/authorization system. When the user does not have valid credentials, I return a 401 status code from the proxy I set up to handle the authentication/authorization request. I can't figure out how to get the 401 status code in Meteor and/or Iron:Router and then redirect the user to an unauthorized access page. Any ideas on how to do this?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a [server-side route](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-only).

`server/router.js` (*just has to be on the server, doesn't have to be that file.*)

```
Router.route('/some/route', function () {
  var req = this.request
  var res = this.response
  res.writeHead(401)
  res.end('401 Authorization required.')
}, {where: 'server'})
```